# Calling Graph API with powershell or batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-line, office365

In trying to design a simplified script for use with the office 365 graph API I can't seem to find any way to call it from a simplified outset.

For the use that I have intended for it I really don't want to take the time to build and compile an actual program when everything else can be done from powershell or a batch script.

In specific, I really only want to be able to call the graph API for a list of groups and store the result (in an array or text file).  **Is it possible to call the graph API from powershell or command line and if so, how?**

Comment: Do you know if the API works with C#?  I have no specific knowledge about Graph API, but anything you can call from .NET you can also call from PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

> In specific, I really only want to be able to call the graph API for a list of groups and store the result (in an array or text file).

If you just need to export a list of groups. I suggest you using the [Azure Active Directory PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx).

```
$msolcred = get-credential

connect-msolservice -credential $msolcred

Get-MsolGroup | Out-File C:\Workbench\temp\tests\export.txt
```

[image]

> Is it possible to call the graph API from powershell or command line and if so, how?

Yes, it is possible, to call the REST API:

First, you need to [Obtaining an Access Token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx#powershellexample)

Then, use the Invoke-RestMethod to call Graph API.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer {your_access_token}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PSMSGRAPH module for this. Can be download from the [gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/psmsgraph/1.0.26.43)

You must register an application in Azure to authenticate and delegate the necessary right to your app. You can do it at the appreg [portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)

Once this is done you just need to auth and run your request.
When running the code you will have to provide a credential to authorize.

```
$username = 'entertheappidhere'
$password = 'entertheapppaswordhere' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$ClientCredential = New-Object -TypeName 
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
$GraphAppParams = @{}
$GraphAppParams.Add('Name','Office365TenantMigration')
$GraphAppParams.Add('ClientCredential',$ClientCredential)
$GraphAppParams.Add('RedirectUri','https://localhost/')
$GraphAppParams.Add('Tenant','yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com')

$GraphApp = New-GraphApplication @GraphAppParams 
# This will prompt you to log in with your O365/Azure credentials. 
$AuthCode = $GraphApp | Get-GraphOauthAuthorizationCode 
$GraphAccessToken = $AuthCode | Get-GraphOauthAccessToken -Resource 'https://graph.microsoft.com/'
$GraphAccessToken | Export-GraphOAuthAccessToken -Path 'f:\O365Report\AccessToken.XML'
$GraphAccessToken =  Import-GraphOAuthAccessToken -Path 'f:\O365Report\AccessToken.XML'
$GraphAccessToken | Update-GraphOAuthAccessToken -Force

### Run the query
Invoke-GraphRequest -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups"-Method GET -AccessToken $GraphAccessToken
```